# pydualsense suddenly stop reading input of PS5 controller

Tags: python, controller, joystick

reading input of PS5 controller using pydualsense get error and unable to read after running few secounds.
error code has more than this, i just paste here top of them

```
from pydualsense import *


def input_check():
    dualsense = pydualsense()
    dualsense.init()
    keys = []
    while True:
        ...
        if dualsense.state.options:
            keys.append('option')
            return 'option'
        elif dualsense.state.ps:
            keys.append('ps')
            return 'ps'
        elif dualsense.state.triangle:
            keys.append('triangle')
            return 'triangle'
        elif dualsense.state.square:
            keys.append('square')
            return 'square'
        elif dualsense.state.cross:
            keys.append('cross')
            return 'cross'
        elif dualsense.state.circle:
            keys.append('circle')
            return 'circle'

    # close device
    dualsense.close()

while True:
    input = input_check()
    print(input)
```

this is error code

```
Exception in thread Thread-113:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda3\envs\fifabot\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-373:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda3\envs\fifabot\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\anaconda3\envs\fifabot\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self.run()
  File "E:\anaconda3\envs\fifabot\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
```

Answer (score 0):

I have self sloved it.
code should be like this

````
from time import sleep

ds = pydualsense()  # open controller
ds.init()  # initialize controller

while True:
    keys = []
    triangle = ds.state.triangle
    if triangle == True:
        keys.append('triangle')
    square = ds.state.square
    if square == True:
        keys.append('square')
    cross = ds.state.cross
    if cross == True:
        keys.append('cross')
    circle = ds.state.circle
    if circle == True:
        keys.append('circle')

    print(keys,ds.state.LX,ds.state.LY)

ds.close() # closing the controller```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).